# Angular Reactive Form - Render control in form array for a string array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a string array of `emails` as below:

```
{
   "streetName": "street 1",
   "emails" : [
     "aaa@stackoverflow.com",
     "yyy@stackoverflow.com"
   ]
}
```

How would I render this in reactive form input fields?

I tried this but not working:

```
<div class="row mt-4" formArrayName="emails">
  <div class="col" *ngFor="let email in myform.get('emails')['controls']; let emailIndex=index">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" formControlName="emailIndex"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The problem was the `*ngFor` part. You have to use `of` for `[ngForOf]` directive. And pass the `emailIndex` with `[formControlName]` attribute.

```
<div
  class="col"
  *ngFor="
    let email of myform.get('emails')['controls'];
    let emailIndex = index
  "
>
  <input type="text" placeholder="" [formControlName]="emailIndex" />
</div>
```

2. Besides, you should also look for the component part for the way how you patch the control. You need to iterate each value in the `data.emails` array and add the `FormControl` to `emails` `FormArray`.

```
for (let index in this.data.emails) {
  (this.myform.controls.emails as FormArray).controls.push(
    new FormControl(this.data.emails[index])
  );
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vmhtpj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: for me it is rendering as `[object Object]`

Comment: Which part that render the `[object Object]`? Can you create a demo in StackBlitz? Thanks.

Comment: I go the issue, I am adding `FormGroup` instead of `FormControl`, your code is correct